# Why the image of books doesn't appear?

Tags: wordpress, themes

Please help me with these problem ! I downloaded Ureeka theme in wordpress and I activate it and works successfully! but i have a problem with showing the image of books , the original theme home page like this :
[look the image of books! showed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDfjI.png)

but on my website looks like below :(
[image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXCjC.png)
 i donnow why ! also i used some different wordpress releases but all the same !! and i used the same size of the first picture for featured image but dont appear please help me ,,

Comment: the image source path is most likely incorrect, what's the src of the images?

Answer (score 0):

The links to the book images in your theme have been broken. Your theme might have support for installing demo content. You will need to contact the vendor of your theme to request installation support and documentation.